# How do I create custom sub menus for MCprep Addon?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I'd like to do my own edit of an add-on so it covers everything I need, I need to create a new menu when doing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and a sub tab when selecting a mode like on the pictures below:

[image]

[image]

You can download the addon [here](https://github.com/TheDuckCow/MCprep). Should be v3.0.2, to see the code, unzip the folder and open files "mcprep_ui" "spawner" "meshswap", I'm not sure if I'm missing one more file but these are the ones I believe that are related to the menus.

Comment: Thanks to @brockmann for editing the question and making it more specific! :D

Comment: It is not clear what your actual question is as well as what your goals are. " ...so it covers everything I need" it would make sense to define "everything I need".

Comment: Suggest asking on the  [issues page](https://github.com/TheDuckCow/MCprep/issues)